# Turning a class member into an object member after class declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x

Usually one initializes class members inside the class (not into the constructor) and the references them via `MyClass.mymember` instead of `self.mymember`.

However I noticed that I can actually reference the member later via `self.mymember`. Further, I can even overwrite it. This has the very curious effect, that the class member becomes an instance member.

This effect can be seen in the following code with `property_cache` of `MyClass`.

It is really helpful in this context, because now the object `property_cache` (not the class `PropertyCache`!) can be used as a decorator *and* it is a instance member of `myclass`(not a class member of `MyClass`!).

However, the effect that a class member is turned into an instance member after the declaration of `MyClass` is very unexpected. I did not even consider that such a thing is possible and I don't quite understand this mechanism.

Can someone shed some light on it and possible reference some literature on this? I did not find a description in the documentation of python.

```
class PropertyCache:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}

    def reset(self):
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(this, function):

        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if function.__qualname__ not in self.property_cache.cache:
                self.property_cache.cache[function.__qualname__] = function(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return self.property_cache.cache[function.__qualname__]
        return wrapper


class MyClass:

    property_cache = PropertyCache()

    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.parameter = parameter
        self.property_cache = PropertyCache()

    def fit(self, data):
        print('fit')
        self.intermediate_data_ = data + self.parameter + 2
        self.property_cache.reset()
        return self

    @property
    @property_cache
    def trans1(self):
        print('trans 1')
        return self.intermediate_data_ / self.parameter / 2

    @property
    @property_cache
    def trans2(self):
        print('trans 2')
        return self.intermediate_data_ / self.parameter / 5


myclass = MyClass(2)
myclass.fit(10)
myclass.trans1
myclass.trans1
myclass.trans2
myclass.fit(15)
myclass.trans1
myclass.trans1
myclass.trans2

myclass2 = MyClass(3)
myclass2.fit(15)
myclass2.trans2
myclass2.trans2

myclass.trans2
```

Comment: You're not turning a class member into an instance member. You're *hiding* the class-level `property_cache`. This seems almost certainly the wrong thing to do in the code you posted, and I'm not sure why you want to do it.

Comment: Looking closer, it looks like you're only using the instance-level `property_cache` for its `cache` attribute, and you're only using the class-level `property_cache` for its `__call__`. It doesn't look like there's any reason to bundle these things into a single type, and the name reuse just makes things even harder to reason about.

Comment: Class name definitions - such as the definition of all static fields, and all methods, _and_ the execution of all decorators on these methods - are executed at a different point in time than the constructor itself. So what's likely happening is that all decorators are executed on the initial property cache, and then the field `property_cache` is changed for each _instance_ in the constructor. Hence, when you call `fit`, my guess would be that you don't reset any cached value, but only the instance cache, for which you haven't assigned any methods.

Comment: Read more on execution order  [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html)

Comment: And for the overarching topic, i.e. "what are classes, actually", read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: What I actually want to do, is only have an instance-level `property_cache`. Obviously I want to have one cache per instance, but also use `property_cache` as a decorator, use the instance-level `__call__()` method. The problem is that I cannot use `@self.property_cache` as decorator. Considering what you wrote, it seems to me the reason why this works, is because the class-level `__call__()` is not using its self-reference `this` to access the cache-dict, but the goes via the `function`'s `self.property_cache`. I should give them distinct names; it will still work.